# NSURLSession with delegate is not working on main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, delegates, nsurlsession

I want that NSURLSession's delegation is called on the main thread. When I passed `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]` to `delegateQueue`, the delegation was not called.

```objective-c
    @interface NSURLSessionTests : XCTestCase<NSURLSessionDataDelegate>
    {
        @private
        dispatch_semaphore_t _semaphore;
    }
    @end

    @implementation NSURLSessionTests

    - (void)testWithRequest{
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://example.com/"]];
        
        NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration
                                                              delegate:self
                                                        delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
        NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request];
        
        _semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
        [dataTask resume];
        
        NSLog(@"Start: %@", dataTask);
        
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(_semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    }

    # pragma mark NSURLSessionDataDelegate

    - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask
                                    didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
                                      completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition disposition))completionHandler {
        NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse: %@", NSThread.currentThread);
        NSLog(@"%@", response);
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionResponseAllow);
    }

    - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
    {
        NSLog(@"didReceiveData: %@", NSThread.currentThread);
        NSLog(@"%@", data);
    }

    - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error
    {
        NSLog(@"didCompleteWithError: %@", NSThread.currentThread);
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(_semaphore);
    }
    @end
```

The executed results are below.

```
Test Suite 'Selected tests' started at 2020-10-19 16:53:56.013
Test Suite 'Tests.xctest' started at 2020-10-19 16:53:56.014
Test Suite 'NSURLSessionTests' started at 2020-10-19 16:53:56.014
Test Case '-[NSURLSessionTests testWithRequest]' started.
2020-10-19 16:53:56.016936+0900 xctest[91856:6495007] Start: LocalDataTask <A9DFF949-ED27-4C5E-8E15-93113442D876>.<1>
```

It is freezing here. All the delegation methods aren't called.

if I pass `nil` to `delegateQueue`, it worked as expected.

```objectivec
        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration
                                                          delegate:self
                                                     delegateQueue:nil];
```

but not on the main thread.

```
Test Suite 'Selected tests' started at 2020-10-19 17:10:03.227
Test Suite 'Tests.xctest' started at 2020-10-19 17:10:03.228
Test Suite 'NSURLSessionTests' started at 2020-10-19 17:10:03.228
Test Case '-[NSURLSessionTests testWithRequest]' started.
2020-10-19 17:10:03.230845+0900 xctest[91910:6506707] Start: LocalDataTask <44C2D9FA-09D3-4C25-9129-B164D451836D>.<1>
2020-10-19 17:10:03.629414+0900 xctest[91910:6506750] didReceiveResponse: <NSThread: 0x7f8d2281f480>{number = 2, name = (null)}
2020-10-19 17:10:03.629867+0900 xctest[91910:6506750] <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7f8d20f333e0> { URL: http://example.com/ } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
    ...
} }
2020-10-19 17:10:03.630215+0900 xctest[91910:6506750] didReceiveData: <NSThread: 0x7f8d2281f480>{number = 2, name = (null)}
2020-10-19 17:10:03.630459+0900 xctest[91910:6506750] #NSData 1KB(1256)
2020-10-19 17:10:03.630940+0900 xctest[91910:6506750] didCompleteWithError: <NSThread: 0x7f8d2281f480>{number = 2, name = (null)}
2020-10-19 17:10:03.631095+0900 xctest[91910:6506750] (null)
Test Case '-[NSURLSessionTests testWithRequest]' passed (0.403 seconds).
Test Suite 'NSURLSessionTests' passed at 2020-10-19 17:10:03.632.
  Executed 1 test, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.403 (0.404) seconds
Test Suite 'Tests.xctest' passed at 2020-10-19 17:10:03.633.
  Executed 1 test, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.403 (0.405) seconds
Test Suite 'Selected tests' passed at 2020-10-19 17:10:03.633.
  Executed 1 test, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.403 (0.406) seconds
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Why isn't the delegation called with `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]`? How do I work on the main thread?

### 2020/10/23 Edited

As commented, the Xctest code worked when I changed to `XCTestExpectation` instead of `dispatch_semaphore_t`.

```objectivec
@interface NSURLSessionTests : XCTestCase<NSURLSessionDataDelegate>
{
    @private
    XCTestExpectation *_expection;
}
@end

@implementation NSURLSessionTests
- (void)testWithRequest{
    _expection = [self expectationWithDescription:@"UIDocument is opened."];
    
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://example.com/"]];
    
...
    
    [dataTask resume];
    [self waitForExpectations:[NSArray arrayWithObject:_expection] timeout:12.0];
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didCompleteWithError: %@", NSThread.currentThread);
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
    [_expection fulfill];
}
@end
```

But my app code doesn't still work. When I checked the app code, I found processing waiting for the end of HTTP request.

```objectivec
- (void)startSync
{
    FcLicenseChecker *license = [FcLicenseChecker sharedInstance];
    if(!license.isCheckRunning)
    {
        [license execute];
    }
    
    [license waitUntilCheckFinished];
...
```

```objectivec
@implementation FcLicenseChecker

- (void)waitUntilCheckFinished
{
    while (_isCheckRunning)
    {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1]];
    }
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error
{
  ...
  _isCheckRunning = NO;
}
```

It was doing roop in `waitUntilCheckFinished` without the delegation called.

I think that the way using `[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate` for waiting for the end worked with `NSURLConnection`'s delegation, but not with `NSURLSession`.

I think that it will work to change to fire the next process in `didCompleteWithError` instead of waiting for the end, but it is very hard because there are many codes using this class.

Is there a way to wait for the end with `NSURLSession`?

Comment: I struggle to understand your code, but I think I understand the question. Why don't you just switch to the main thread when you need to using ```dispatch_async ( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ { ...stuf you want to do on main... } );```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to do asynchronous unit testing. Take a look at this Apple doc that shows how to do this correctly with `XCTestExpectation`: [Testing Asynchronous Operations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/asynchronous_tests_and_expectations/testing_asynchronous_operations_with_expectations?language=objc). Their example is only written in Swift, but you should be able to translate it to Objective-C easily.

Comment: @Tyler I thought it was the same as `dispatch_semaphore_wait` but I tried what you said, it worked! However, my problem isn't solved yet. It works on XCTest, but not on my app. I think the problem is about the multithread issue. I will try more. Anyway thanks.

Comment: @skaak As you said, when I used `dispatch_async` in the delegation method, it worked on the main thread, but it's only on XCTest, not on my app. On the app, the `dispatch_async` block wasn't called. I don't know why.

Comment: Ok - that *should* have been called on the main definitely - can you post your new code, just the delegate and where you call it. BTW why do you use a semaphore? Im asking as it could be the perfect solution here or it could be very wrong so I just want some context to comment on that as well.